# Mule custom validation with property or parameter

Tags: java, validation, mule, anypoint-studio

We are trying migrating our existing code to Mule, in order to complete all the validation, we need custom validator to be more powerful to support the following:

```
<RULE>
    <ID crosssite="Y" stoponerr="Y">CheckAmount</ID>
    <MSG>Err_CheckAmount</MSG>
    <PARAM name="isIndex"></PARAM>
    <PARAM name="ccyIdField"></PARAM>
    <PARAM name="ccyListField"></PARAM>
    <PARAM name="ccyField">HKD</PARAM>
</RULE>
```

where CheckAmount is a validator class, and take a list of parameter, so it can validate everything based the parameter.

i noticed this issue has already been raised many years ago in the comment of below.
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6087

so does mule has anything like the this?

```
<validation:all doc:name="Validate min">
        <validation:validations>
            <validation:custom-validator class="test.CheckVal" message="Err_CheckValue">
                **<validation:param name="CITY">HK</validation:param>
                <validation:param name="MIN">20</validation:param>
                <validation:param name="MAX">50</validation:param>**
            </validation:custom-validator>
            <validation:is-false expression=""/>
        </validation:validations>
</validation:all>
```

So when i implement Validator interface, i can get do the validation based on the parameters.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a Spring bean as validator. All you configurable properties must be accessible by public get/set methods (in this example the properties min and max).

Example Java class:

```
package de.codecentric;

import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.extension.validation.api.ValidationResult;
import org.mule.extension.validation.api.Validator;
import org.mule.extension.validation.internal.ImmutableValidationResult;

public class CustomValidator implements Validator {
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationResult validate(MuleEvent event) {
        Object payload = event.getMessage().getPayload();
        if (!(payload instanceof Number)) {
            return ImmutableValidationResult.error("Not a number: " +     payload);
        }
        Number number = (Number) payload;
        if (number.intValue() > max) {
            return ImmutableValidationResult.error("Too big: " + number);
        }
        if (number.intValue() < min) {
            return ImmutableValidationResult.error("Too small: " + number);
        }
        return ImmutableValidationResult.ok();
    }
}
```

Then have to create an instance as Spring bean from this:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="MyValidator" class="de.codecentric.CustomValidator">
        <spring:property name="min" value="10" />
        <spring:property name="max" value="20" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

And use it in your Mule flow like this:

```
<validation:custom-validator doc:name="Validation" ref="MyValidator"/>
```

Comment: Hi , when I try to implement the validato interface. It's default implementation ooks like this: @Override
 public ValidationResult validate() {
  return null;
 }
How do i access the mule event ?

Comment: Hi, I am getting the below error with this configuration :  Invalid content was found starting with element 'validation:custom-validator'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.

Comment: This whole stuff is for Mule3. Are you still using Mule3? Or the current 4.3?